# How to get first preg match elements

Tags: preg-match, preg-match-all

I need with preg_match_all() to extract all [ANY_TEXT-pb] blocks.

My code:

```
$content = 'START Text1 [news-block] text2 [title1-pb] text3 text4 [title2-pb] text5 END';
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)pb\]/si', $content, $codes);
print_r($codes[0]);
```

What I need to get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [title1-pb]
    [1] => [title2-pb]
)
```

What I get now:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [news-block] text2 [title1-pb]
    [1] => [title2-pb]
)
```

How to detect the first "[" element from the same block? Looks like now this preg takes first "[" from all string.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the desired result, you should not cross matching square brackets using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

For a match only, you don't need the capture group, so you can omit the parenthesis:

```
\[[^][]*pb\]
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV2lMg/1):